# Converting array to string in javascript and back to array in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array in javascript, when click a button, I need to print the array as html input value. I did this and it works:

```
myString = JSON.stringify(results);
```

After I got the string in php, `json_decode($results,true)` got null return;
How to get the string back to array in php? Or, should I use other ways to convert array to string in javascript at the first place?

### update:

This solution works:

```
$results= preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $results);
$results = json_decode( $results,true );
```

How ever, I hope there's a better way.

Comment: did you check `json_last_error()`? And unserialize is for undoing `serialize()` output. They're two **COMPLETELY** different formats, and are NOT interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks! I var_dump the json_last_error, it's 4

Comment: http://php.net/json_last_error lists the constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have magic quotes on. Disable it to stop the massive multitude of backslashes.